# How to "lock" Vuetify v-list-item-group selection?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a [`v-list-item-group`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups) for having a stateful list items. The thing is I want to **disable altering** the currently selected item once any is selected.

To achieve that, I tried adding a `watch` on the selected item and reverting the `v-model` of the old value of it. However, it ends up in an infinite loop (you know, I assign new value inside its own watcher).

```html
<template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item-group v-model="model" :mandatory="!!model">
      <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="`item-${i}`" :value="item">
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title v-text="item"></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-item-group>
  </v-list>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3'
      ],
      model: null,
    }),
    watch: {
      model (val, oldVal) {
        // This logic will change the value and trigger watcher again and again
        this.val = oldVal
    }
  }
</script>
```

So, how to **lock** the selection of a `v-list-item-group? -apparently the snippet above is not the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add a property in your `data()` method, such as `lockSelection`. Initialize it as `false`.
2. Add a `v-bind:disabled="lockSelection"` attribute to your v-list-items.
3. Add a `@click="lockSelection = true"` listener to your v-list-items.

```
<template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item-group v-model="model" :mandatory="!!model">
      <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="`item-${i}`" :value="item"
        :disabled="lockSelection" @click="lockSelection=true">
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title v-text="item"></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-item-group>
  </v-list>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3'
      ],
      model: null,
      lockSelection: false
    }),
    watch: {
      model (val, oldVal) {
        // This logic will change the value and trigger watcher again and again
        this.val = oldVal
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In similar cases you don't nead to disable the item, you can use Mandatory list which have at least one element selected https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups/#mandatory