# vuetify list-item-group how to unselect the selected record

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify 2.0 view-list which when selected populates a form for editing (standard list-detail design pattern).  The selected item gets highlighted in the list which is good (I know I can turn it off...).  What I would like to do is if the selected item is selected again to clear the form, or if the user clicks the [Clear] button to un-select the list item.

I can't see anything in either the App or Vuetify objects that is tracking this state.  How do I wire up the populated state of the form with the selected/active status of the view-list-item

Example codepen
https://codepen.io/E4CAaron/pen/NWWeBXZ

Example Code below:
Script;

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: {
        msg: 'Hello',
        email: '',
    rules:[
      {id:"1","name":"rule one",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"},
      {id:"2",name:"rule two",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"},
      {id:"3",name:"rule three",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"},
      {id:"4",name:"rule four",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"},
      {id:"5",name:"rule five",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"}

    ],
    SelectedRule:{},
    state:{
      formIsDirty:false
    }
    },
    methods: {
      editRule(rule){
        this.SelectedRule = Object.assign({},rule);
        this.state.formIsDirty = false
      },
      clearRule(){
        this.SelectedRule ={}
      },
      dirtyForm(){
        this.state.formIsDirty =true;
      },
      onScroll (e) {
        this.offsetTop = e.target.scrollTop
      },
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<v-app>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
       <v-col cols="4">

        <v-list 
                dense
                id="scroll-target"
                style="max-height: 100%"
                class="overflow-y-auto" 
                >
          <v-subheader>Rules</v-subheader>
          <v-list-item-group
                             color="warning"
                             dense
                             >

            <v-list-item 
                         v-for="rule in rules" 
                         :key="rule.id"
                         @click="editRule(rule)"
                         >
              {{rule.name}}
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-col> 
      <v-col cols="8">
        <v-form fixed >
          <v-text-field label="Rule Name" v-model="SelectedRule.name" @change="dirtyForm"></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Conversion Rate" v-model="SelectedRule.conversion_rate" @change="dirtyForm"></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Round To Nearest" v-model="SelectedRule.round_to_nearest" @change="dirtyForm"></v-text-field>
          <v-checkbox label="is Brand RRP" v-model="SelectedRule.isRRP" checked @change="dirtyForm"></v-checkbox>
          <v-btn color="primary" :disabled="!state.formIsDirty">Save</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="info" @click="clearRule()">Clear</v-btn>

        </v-form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `v-model` to the `v-list-item-group` and you will be able to change the selected item of `v-list-item-group` programmatically.

Now, step-by-step. First, add `v-model`:

```
 <v-list-item-group
    v-model="rule"
    color="warning"
    dense
 >
```

Then add the `rule` in `data` and watch it. If it became `null`, clear your form.

```
...
data: {
  ...,
  rule: null
},
watch: {
  rule: function () {
    if (this.rule==null) this.clearRule()
  }
},
...
```

And finally, clear `rule` when the user clicks Clear button. Modify your `clearRule` method like this:

```
clearRule(){
  this.SelectedRule ={}
  this.rule = nul
},
```

Here is working code snippet:

```js
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data: {
            msg: 'Hello',
            email: '',
        rules:[
          {id:"1","name":"rule one",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"},
          {id:"2",name:"rule two",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"},
          {id:"3",name:"rule three",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"},
          {id:"4",name:"rule four",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"},
          {id:"5",name:"rule five",conversion_rate:"1.17",round_to_nearest:".05",isRRP:"0"}
          
        ],
        SelectedRule:{},
        state:{
          formIsDirty:false
        },
        rule:null
        },
        watch: {
          rule: function () {
          if (this.rule==null) this.clearRule()
        }
        },
        methods: {
          editRule(rule){
            this.SelectedRule = Object.assign({},rule);
            this.state.formIsDirty = false
          },
          clearRule(){
            this.SelectedRule ={}
            this.rule = null
          },
          dirtyForm(){
            this.state.formIsDirty =true;
          },
          onScroll (e) {
            this.offsetTop = e.target.scrollTop
          },
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.1.1/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.1.1/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<v-app>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="4">
        {{msg}}
        <v-list 
                dense
                id="scroll-target"
                style="max-height: 100%"
                class="overflow-y-auto" 
                >
          <v-subheader>Rules</v-subheader>
          <v-list-item-group v-model='rule'
                             color="warning"
                             dense
                             >

            <v-list-item 
                         v-for="rule in rules" 
                         :key="rule.id"
                         @click="editRule(rule)"
                         >
              {{rule.name}}
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-col> 
      <v-col cols="8">
        <v-form fixed >
          <v-text-field label="Rule Name" v-model="SelectedRule.name" @change="dirtyForm"></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Conversion Rate" v-model="SelectedRule.conversion_rate" @change="dirtyForm"></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field label="Round To Nearest" v-model="SelectedRule.round_to_nearest" @change="dirtyForm"></v-text-field>
          <v-checkbox label="is Brand RRP" v-model="SelectedRule.isRRP" checked @change="dirtyForm"></v-checkbox>
          <v-btn color="primary" :disabled="!state.formIsDirty">Save</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="info" @click="clearRule()">Clear</v-btn>

        </v-form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the rule if it was already selected (as stored in the `SelectedRule` variable, and in your edit rule method, simply set the SelectedRule value to the empty object.

```
editRule(rule){
  if (this.SelectedRule.id === rule.id) {
    this.SelectedRule = {}
  } else {
    this.SelectedRule = Object.assign({},rule);
    this.state.formIsDirty = false
  }
}
```

I've tested this code on the Codepen you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response; unfortunately that only solves part of the challenge.  You are successfully clearing the form when the list item is unselected, but it does not clear the list item highlight when the clear button is clicked.  Looking at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878458/how-to-lock-vuetify-v-list-item-group-selection I think the only way to do it is to store the selected item in the data using v-model; when you then reset the data attribute the active status is removed as a result of the 2-way binding.